# Largest number of times square root can be calculated on numbers between 2 intervals

Tags: java, math

I wrote a simple program to calculate the maximum number of times square root can be calculated on a number , input is an interval from num1 to num2
eg: 
if the input is (1,20), answer is 2, since square root of 16 is 4 , and square root of 4 is 2 .

```
 int max = 0;
    for (int i = num1; i <= num2; i++) {
        boolean loop = true;
        int count = 0;
        int current = i;
        if (i == 1) {
            count++;
        } else {
            while (loop) {
                double squareRoot = Math.sqrt(current);
                if (isCurrentNumberPerfectSquare(squareRoot)) {
                    count++;
                    current = (int) squareRoot;
                } else {
                    loop = false;
                }
            }
        }

        if (count > max) {
            max = count;
        }
    }
    return max;


static boolean isCurrentNumberPerfectSquare(double number) {
    return ((number - floor(number)) == 0);
}
```

I get the answer, but was wondering wether this can be improved using some mathematical way ?
Any suggestions ?

Comment: What about square root of 9 (3) and square root of 1 (1)?

Comment: we calculate the largest number of times root can be calculated, if the input is 1,10, answer is 1, since there are 3 perfect squares  (1,4,9) and we can calculate the square root of each of them only once.

Comment: if the input is (1, 3) answer is 1, since there is only one perfect square (1)  and square root of that is the same - which is 1

Comment: The way you've worded the question, we understand it as equivalent to *how many perfect squares are there in this range?*. If you're expected to test that the computed square root is also a perfect square, then you probably want to use recursion here.

Comment: not exactly number of perfect square, eg:. if the input is (2,20), there are three perfect squares 4,16,9,  but for the case i have presented answer would be 2, because root of 16 is 4 (count is one), root of 4 is 2 (now count is 2), we stop at 2, since 2 is not a perfect square

Comment: done, i thought i marked the correct one first time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid more confusion here my final answer to this topic.
A combination of both previously mentioned approaches.

What 'Parameswar' is looking for is the largest perfect square formed by the lowest base.

```
Step 1 -
To get that calculate the largest possible perfect square based on your num2 value.
If it is outside your range, you have no perfect square within.

Step 2 -
If it is within your range, you have to check all perfect square formed by a lower base value with a higher number of times.

Step 3 -
If you find one that is within your range, replace your result with the new result and proceed to check lower values. (go back to Step 2)

Step 4 -
Once the value you check is <= 2 you have already found the answer.
```

Here some sample implementation:

```
    static class Result {
        int base;
        int times;
    }

    static boolean isCurrentNumberPerfectSquare(double number) {
        return ((number - Math.floor(number)) == 0);
    }

    private static int perfectSquare(int base, int times) {

        int value = base;
        for (int i = times; i > 0; i--) {
            value = (int) Math.pow(base, 2);
        }
        return value;
    }

    private static Result calculatePerfectSquare(int perfectSquare) {

        Result result = new Result();
        result.base = (int) Math.sqrt(perfectSquare);
        result.times = 1;

        while (result.base > 2 && isCurrentNumberPerfectSquare(Math.sqrt(result.base))) {
            result.base = (int) Math.sqrt(result.base);
            result.times += 1;
        }

        System.out.println(perfectSquare + " -> " + result.base + " ^ " + result.times);
        return result;
    }

    static int maxPerfectSquares(int num1, int num2) {

        int largestPerfectSqr = (int) Math.pow(Math.floor(Math.sqrt(num2)), 2);
        if (largestPerfectSqr < num1) {
            return 0;
        }

        Result result = calculatePerfectSquare(largestPerfectSqr);

        int currentValue = result.base;

        while (currentValue > 2) {

            // check lower based values
            currentValue--;

            int newValue = perfectSquare(currentValue, result.times + 1);
            if (newValue >= num1 && newValue < num2) {

                result = calculatePerfectSquare(newValue);
                currentValue = result.base;
            }
        }

        return result.times;
    }
```

Comment: @Parameswar: Now you marked the incorrect answer of 'Chrisvin Jem' as correct. I was talking about this one.

Comment: Hmm ... no its not ;). you commented the correct one but the accpted answer is still the other one. Or my eyes are just bad ....

Comment: na. i have rented out my brain, so its not functioning properly :)

Answer (score 0):

Edit - My assumption is incorrect. Refer to the answer provided by "second".

---

You can remove the outer loop, num2 can be directly used to determine the number with the maximum number of recursive square roots.

requiredNumber = square(floor(sqrt(num2)));

You just need to check to see if the requiredNumber exists in the range [num1, num2] after finding it.

So the refactoring code would look something like this,

```
int requiredNumber = Math.pow(floor(Math.sqrt(num2)),2);
int numberOfTimes=0;
if(requiredNumber>=num1) {
    if (requiredNumber == 1) {
        numberOfTimes=1;
    } else{
        while (isCurrentNumberPerfectSquare(requiredNumber)) {
            numberOfTimes++;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: i did not get you,

Comment: For example, if you need to find for num1 = 1, num2 = 20. requiredNumber =square(floor(sqrt(20)))=square(floor(4.4721))=square(4)=16.

Comment: Now that you know that the number with the biggest number of recursive square roots is 16. You just have to check to see if it is greater than num1, because there might be a case where there are no perfect squares between num1 and num2. Get it?

Comment: @Parameswar The idea is pretty simple, the largest number will obviously have the biggest 'square root', if the root is a decimal, then that means that the square of the floor of the decimal root will be the biggest perfect square that's lesser than or equal to num2. We simply make an extra check to ensure that the number is also greater than or equal to num1.

Comment: i need the number of times actually, not the largest number, but let me read your answer once more, :)

Comment: @Parameswar Yea, I know, you already have the code for finding the number of times. All I'm saying is that you can remove the outer loop because it's unnecessary. The inner loop is enough to find the number of times once the biggest perfect square number is known. :)

Comment: @Parameswar I've edited my answer to include the code utilizing my said logic.

Answer (score 0):

Edit 4: for a more optimal approach check my other answer.
I just leave this here if anybody wants to try to follow my thought process ;)

---

Edit 3:
Using prime numbers is wrong, use lowest non perfect square instead
Example [35,37]

Edit 2:
Now that I think about it there is a even better approach, especially if you assume that num1 and num2 cover a larger range.

Start with the lowest <s>prime number</s> 'non perfect square' and
calculate the maximum perfect square that fits into your range.

If you have found one, you are done.
If not continue with the next <s>prime number</s> 'non perfect square'.

---

As a example that works well enough for smaller ranges:

I think you can improve the outerloop. There is no need to test every number.

If you know the smallest perfect square, you can just proceed to the next perfect square in the sequence.

For example:
[16, 26]

```
16 -> 4 -> 2 ==> 2 perfect squares
No neeed to test 17 to 24
25 -> 5 ==> 1 perfect square
```

and so on ...

@Chrisvin Jem
Your assumption is not correct, see example above

Edit:
Added some code

```
    static int countPerfectSquares(int current) {

       int count = 0;

       while (true) {
            double squareRoot = Math.sqrt(current);
            if (isCurrentNumberPerfectSquare(squareRoot)) {
                count++;
                current = (int) squareRoot;
            } else {
               return count;
            }
        }
    }

    static boolean isCurrentNumberPerfectSquare(double number) {
        return ((number - Math.floor(number)) == 0);
    }

    static int numPerfectSquares(int num1, int num2) {

        int max = 0;
        if (num1 == 1) {
            max = 1;
        }

        int sqr = Math.max(2, (int) Math.floor(Math.sqrt(num1)));

        int current = (int) Math.pow(sqr, 2);
        if (current < num1) {
            current = (int) Math.pow(++sqr, 2);
        }

        while (current <= num2) {
            max = Math.max(countPerfectSquares(current), max);
            current = (int) Math.pow(++sqr, 2);
        }

        return max;
    }
```

Comment: How will you find the next perfect square if you know the smallest?

Comment: Added some code (and edited it some more times) ... this should work. The base requirement is to have a perfect square so we only need to test those.

Comment: See Edit3: replaced prime number with 'non perfect square'. Example [35,37] ... try 2,3,5 and finally 6. That makes this approach only viable for larger ranges. The previous example performs better for smaller ranges. I wonder if you can combine both approaches into a faster algorithm.

Comment: Okay, I'm completely confused now. Could you elaborate your reasoning behind edit 2 and edit 3.

Comment: What he is basically looking for is the largest perfect square formed by the lowest base. To avoid more confusion I'll add another answer and provide some new code with a combination of both approaches.

Comment: Okay, added a new answer. I hope that makes the whole thing less confusing. (The main reason between edit2 and edit3 was, that I noticed prime values was wrong. In the case of [35,37] the answer is obviously 6, which is not a prime number. Thats why I replaced 'prime number' with lowest non perfect square value.)